# How to call a method from controller more once time? AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Sorry if the question is really dumb, however, I couldn't find how to solve it.

I have a very simple methid in a controller:

```
public string ExactSeconds()
{
   string str = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();
   return str;            
}
```

The view is simpler than the method:

```
<p id="rData"></p> 
<p id="qqqqq">click me!</p>
```

JavaScriptCode:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#qqqqq').click(function () {
        alert('');
        var url = "/Home/ExactSeconds";
        $.get(url, null, function (data) {                
                $("#rData").html(data);
            });

        });

    });
 });
```

However, When I click at **id="qqqqq"**, then it just uploads data(seconds) just for the first time. Then if I click the second time and the next times, then alert('') works perfectly, however it is not called method ExactSeconds, that is I cannot see updated seconds at the view.

**How to call method ExactSeconds() always when I click at #qqqqq?**

Comment: Why do you have nested $.get() calls?

Comment: And how would `var url = "/Home/ProverbPartialView";` call a method named `ExactSeconds()` - assume you have a typo?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, sorry, it is typo. I've updated m question.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've tried and it really works!:) Post your answer, pls!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I remove your AJAX calls, this works fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#qqqqq').click(function () {
        alert('');
        $("#rData").html(Date.now);
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="rData"></p> 

<p id="qqqqq">click me!</p>
```

Secondly, why do you have nested one AJAX get call inside another. How about just one call?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#qqqqq').click(function () {
        alert('');
        var url = "/Home/ProverbPartialView";
        $.get(url, null, function (data) {
            $("#rData").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried without nested Ajax get call, however I cannot read new data from method ExactSeconds. I really need to take data from controller method ExactSeconds, not by JavaScript function Date.now;

Comment: I even cannot enter to breakpoint in the ExactMethod, if I click the second time at the 'qqqqq'.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#qqqqq').click(function () {
        alert('');
        var url = "/Home/ProverbPartialView";
        $.get(url, null, function (data) {                
            $.get(url, null, function (data) {
                $("#rData").empty();
                $("#rData").html(data);
            });

        });

    });
 });
```

Try this by adding $("#rData")..empty(); in the code

Comment: What difference would that make. The `.html()` method replaces existing data.